# C# Excel data to 2D array Error

Tags: c#

I am trying to pull Excel data to an array and I keep receiving this error any help would be great.

Thanks.

```
string[,] Datavalue = new string[dataGridView1.Rows.Count,dataGridView1.Columns.Count];

foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    foreach(DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
    {              
        Datavalue[row.Index, col.Index] =
          dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells[col.Index].Value.ToString();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTXvh.png)

Comment: One suggestion, make use of `catch` block :)

Comment: When you are dealing with 2d array in Excel you'd need to use object[,] instead of string[,] regardless if all the data in array is string.